# Using QGIS 3.0 API for layout?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to generate an atlas with python in qgis 3.0. I have :

```
projectInstance= QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
for comp in projectLayoutManager.printLayouts():
    if comp.atlas().enabled():
        comp.atlas().beginRender() 
        nbobj = comp.atlas().updateFeatures()
        comp.atlas().first()
        for i in range(0, comp.atlas().count ()):
            comp.atlas().refreshCurrentFeature ()
            exporter =  QgsLayoutExporter(comp.atlas().layout () )
            pdf_settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings () #dpi?
            exporter.exportToImage (<filename>, pdf_settings)
        comp.atlas().endRender()
```

But I would like the filename to have some attributes of the atlas feature.

How do I get the value of the attribute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simplify this script considerably in QGIS 3.0:

```
projectInstance= QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()

image_settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()
image_settings.dpi = 300 # or whatever you want

for comp in projectLayoutManager.printLayouts():
    if comp.atlas().enabled():
        result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToImage(comp.atlas(), 
                            baseFilePath='c:/temp/my_atlas', extension='.png', settings=image_settings)
        if not result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
            print(error)
```

To control the generated filenames, you need to set an expression for the atlas filenames, e.g.:

```
comp.atlas().setFilenameExpression('"some_attribute" || '_export' )
```

Answer (score 4):

Great, it's gone! thank ndawson.

My new code write atlas result in subdirectories, if can help anyone

```
import os
folder = "D:\CARTE_THEMATIQUE\OUTPUT"
projectInstance= QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()

for comp in projectLayoutManager.printLayouts():
    comp.atlas().setFilenameExpression( "CODE_CENTRE  ||'/'||  CODE_CONTRAT"  )
    image_settings = QgsLayoutExporter(comp.atlas().layout () ).ImageExportSettings()
    image_settings.dpi = 100 # or whatever you want
    if comp.atlas().enabled():
        (filepath, filename) = os.path.split(folder +'\\' + comp.atlas().currentFilename () +'png')
        if not os.path.exists(filepath): 
            os.makedirs(filepath)
        result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToImage(comp.atlas(), baseFilePath=filepath, extension='.png', settings=image_settings)
        if not result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
            print(error)
```